# What is equivalent to pytorch lstm num_layers?

Tags: python, pytorch, lstm

I'm a beginner in PyTorch. From the lstm [description](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.LSTM.html), I learned that I can create a stacked lstm with 3 layers by:

```py
layer = torch.nn.LSTM(128, 512, num_layers=3)
```

Then in the `forward` function, I can do:

```py
def forward(x, state):
    x, state = layer(x, state)
    return x, (state[0].detach(), state[1].detach())
```

And I can pass `state` from batch to batch.
But if I create 3 lstm layers, what is the equivalent to that if I want to implement the same stacked layers myself?

```py
layer1 = torch.nn.LSTM(128, 512, num_layers=1)
layer2 = torch.nn.LSTM(128, 512, num_layers=1)
layer3 = torch.nn.LSTM(128, 512, num_layers=1)
```

In this case, what should go into the `forward` function and get the returned `state`?
I also tried to look at the [source code](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/_modules/torch/nn/modules/rnn.html#LSTM) of pytorch lstm, but in the `forward` function it calls a `_VF` module which I cannot find where it is defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you define `state` as a list of the 3 layers' states, then

```
def forward(x, state):
    x, s0 = layer1(x, state[0])
    x, s1 = layer2(x, state[1])
    x, s2 = layer3(x, state[2])
    return x, [s0.detach(), s1.detach(), s2.detach()]
```